# What can go wrong with series solutution - conflicting answers for two different but seemingly equally valid methods

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this equation to solve, where $A=A(r)$:

$$rA'+A=1- Cr^2$$

I attempt 2 metods, they give different answers. I think the first one is the right one, see them below:

---

### Method I

Rewrite LHS:

$$(rA)'=1-Cr^2$$

Integrate up:

$$rA = r-\frac{1}{3}Cr^3+B$$

Get result:

$$\bbox[5px,border:3px solid green]{A=1+\frac{B}{r}-\frac{1}{3}Cr^2}$$

---

### Method II

Write $A$ as:
$$A=\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}a_n r^n$$
Rewrite LHS:
$$\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}(n a_n+a_n)r^n=1-Cr^2$$
This has to hold for all $r$s, so match coefficients of different powers of $r$, get result:

$$\bbox[5px,border:3px solid red]{A=1-\frac{C}{3}r^2}$$

---

**What am I doing wrong in this second method?**

Comment: I think you mean LHS, not RHS (in both places). And in the green box, the first term should be $1$, not $r$.

Comment: Thank you, corrected!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In method II, note that the term for $n=-1$ is zero regardless of the value of $a_{-1}$. So $a_{-1}=B$, where $B$ is an arbitrary constant, and together with what you already had, this recovers the answer from method I.